# sql query returning multiple result using WHERE

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

There is a table name `Top_Up`. Its current snapshot is:
[image: Top_Up Table]

When I run query `SELECT * FROM Top_Up WHERE Top_up_ID = (round(random() * 9 ) + 1);` on it, I am getting random result. Sometimes it is returning with two tuples, sometimes no tuples and sometime one tuple.

To debug I run the query `Select (round(random() * 9 ) + 1);` and it is always returning only one tuple in the result.

**Why I am getting this vague and random result?**

Comment: Can you post the specific rows that you get (or at least the ID values) when you get more than one row? Also, why not just do a `select * from Top_Up where Top_up_ID<=10 order by random() limit 1;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Round is being calculated per row. Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Top_Up ORDER BY (round(random() * 9 ) + 1);
```

If you run your test against your table you should see a much different result:

```
 Select (round(random() * 9 ) + 1) FROM Top_Up `
```

If you just want a random record I would go with:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Top_Up ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: The last query will scale better, where your original query would only select one from the first 10. Not sure if that was intentional or not though, which is why I offered both of them.